# Optimize and Simplify Raycasting Code in Unity for Store Clerk Interaction?

Tags: c#, unity3d, raycasting

I plan to use a raycast for interacting with all things in my games but Im afraid itll be too laggy how can I shorten this code up?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StoreClerkOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject StoreClerk;
    public GameObject Store;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject SCText;

     // Whatever is your max distance (remove if not needed). However, it is nice to 
have a max distance o which your monster can see the player.
    float maxDistance = 10;
    public bool LookingStoreClerk;
    public bool StoreClerkOPEN;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        // Will contain the information of which object the raycast hit
        RaycastHit hit;

        // if raycast hits, it checks if it hit an object with the tag Player
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 
maxDistance)     &&
                    hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("StoreClerk"))

        {
            SCText.SetActive(true);
            LookingStoreClerk = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && LookingStoreClerk)
        {
            StoreClerkOPEN = true;
            SCText.SetActive(false);
            Store.SetActive(true);
            Player.GetComponent<SC_FPSController>().enabled = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }

        if (StoreClerkOPEN) 
        {
            SCText.SetActive(false);
        } 

    }

}
```

A short and easy code to detect if the player is looking at the store clerk and if they are a text pops up and they can click to interact. Problem is the code got slightly complicated and the text and raycast tend to glitch.

Comment: Is this the complete class? It would be helpful to see the definitions of `MonoBehaviour` and `GameObject`.

Answer (score 1):

```
            SCText.SetActive(true);
            LookingStoreClerk = true;
            ...
            SCText.SetActive(false);
```

You never set `LookingStoreClerk` to false.

> the text and raycast tend to glitch.

Not exactly sure what that means,
but perhaps a player who is near the `maxDistance` radius
will register "hit" and "no hit" in rapid succession.
Consider wrapping some hysteresis around it.

More generally, protect the `.Raycast()` call with a guard.

> too laggy

`maxDistance` is conveniently small.
If we *know* we're outside a bounding box, or
[Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), or
[Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance),
then a cheap boolean test will often be able to
save us an expensive raycast probe.

Additionally, when `SCText` is active
there's no point in making any further raycast probes,
since nothing new will happen even if we *do* get a hit.

## comments lie!

```
        // if raycast hits, it checks if it hit an object with the tag Player
        if(Physics.Raycast( ... ) &&
                    hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("StoreClerk"))
```

The comment suggests one thing, while the code says another.

## dead code

```
            StoreClerkOPEN = true;
            SCText.SetActive(false);
            ...
        if (StoreClerkOPEN) 
        {
            SCText.SetActive(false);
        }
```

I don't understand why we have that last line at all.
There's only one way to become OPEN,
and it called `.SetActive()`,
so that final call to `.SetActive()` appears to be a
[no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)).

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the code by reducing redundant checks and combining conditions.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class StoreClerkOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject StoreClerk, Store, Player, SCText;
    float maxDistance = 10;
    bool LookingStoreClerk, StoreClerkOPEN;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance) && hit.collider.CompareTag("StoreClerk"))
        {
            HandleRaycastHit();
        }
    }

    void HandleRaycastHit()
    {
        SCText.SetActive(!StoreClerkOPEN);
        LookingStoreClerk = true;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StoreClerkOPEN = true;
            Store.SetActive(true);
            Player.GetComponent<SC_FPSController>().enabled = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This example eliminates some redundancy and groups related actions into a separate method (`HandleRaycastHit`). It should be easier to manage and less prone to glitches.